# Store some fields from PIG to Hbase

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to extract some part of string and store it to hbase in columns.

Files Content :

```
msgType1   Person xyz has opened Internet:www.google.com from IP:192.123.123.123 for duration 00:15:00

msgType2   Person xyz denied for opening Internet:202.x.x.x from IP:192.123.123.123 reason:unautheticated 

msgType1    Person xyz has opened Internet:202.x.x.x from IP:192.123.123.123 for duration 00:15:00
```

pattern of messages corresponding to msgType is fixed. Now i am trying to store person name, destination , source , duration etc in hbase.

I am trying to to wrtie script in PIG to do this task.
But i am stuck at extracting part.(extracting IP or website name from 'Internet:202.x.x.x' token inside string).

I tried Regular expression but its not working for me. Regex alway throw this error :

```
ERROR 1045: Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.REGEX_EXTRACT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

is there any other way to extract these value and store it to hbase in PIG or other than PIG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you use the REGEX_EXTRACT function ? Have you seen the REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL function ? According to the documentation (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/func.html#regex-extract-all), it should be like this :

```
test = LOAD 'test.csv' USING org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage(',') AS (key:chararray, value:chararray);
test = FOREACH test GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL (value, '(\\S+):(\\S+)')) as (match1:chararray, match2:chararray);
DUMP test;
```

My file is like that :

```
1,a:b
2,c:d
3,
```

Comment: I used Regex like : 

 E = foreach D generate REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'Internet:*') 

and

: E = foreach D generate REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'Internet:*',2)

and many other variation.

Comment: A = LOAD 'yourfile' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (key:chararray, message:chararray);
B = foreach A generate REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'Internet:*');

Comment: Using B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(f1, '(.*)\:(.*)') AS (match1:chararray, match2:chararray);
It throws error : ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 1, column 57.  Encountered: ":" (58), after : "\'(.*)\\"
Details at logfile: /home/pig_1.log


And Using B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(f1, '(.*):(.*)') AS (match1:chararray, match2:chararray);
It throws Error : - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered "" at line 1, column 67.
Was expecting one of:
    
Details at logfile: /home/pig_1.log

Comment: I've done some research and I've corrected my code. It should now work.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's easy to be lazy and not take the step, but you really should use a [user-defined function](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/udf.html) here. Pig is good as a data flow language and not much else, so in order to get the full power out of it, you are going to need to use a lot of UDFs to go through text and do more complicated operations.

The UDF will take a single string as a parameter, then return a tuple that represents `(person, destination, source, duration)`. To use it, you'll do:

```
A = LOAD ...
...
B = FOREACH A GENERATE MyParseUDF(logline);
...
STORE B INTO ...
```

You didn't mention what your HBase row key was, but be sure that's the first element in the relation before storing it.

Comment: I tried UDFs but my UDF was not working propely , Grunt always through some error while running UDF.

Comment: i some cases result was returning in Bag {(xyz),(Internet:www.google.com),(IP:192.123.123.123)} , and that can be stored in hbase.

I am using pig - 0.8.1 CDH3 version

Comment: i didnt get this statement ,"but be sure that's the first element in the relation before storing it." ...